# .net 4 connecting to SQL server open tcp port issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

we are running windows 2008 server IIS7 .NET 4. Website.

Issue description:
IIS stops responding because SQL server has hundreds of tcp connections open. We have ran a port scanner and can see they are from the local ip address. We have profiler running also but we cannot find a way to work out what command or procedure opened the connection that has not been closed correctly.

The SQL connections seem to be coded correctly using "using" statements. Also in any exceptions we check the connection state. With pooling off or on it makes no difference. Killing the connections and restarting iis does clear the issue. This is a production server thus hard to debug. I have tried various tools but we cannot link the tcp connection back to the source. All the connections have the same time stamp which is odd. We have debugged on the beta server with all exceptions showing and nothing found.

I would like some advise on where to start, the code is inherited and the site is busy.

Connection string is:

```
<add key="ConnectionStringSearch" 
     value="pooling=false;Connection Lifetime=90;Password=;Connect Timeout=999;
            Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Initial Catalog;Data Source=2;
            Network Library=DBMSSOCN"/>
```

Comment: Could you post your connection string? Also you say "using" is in use, but does that include DataReaders?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify the code blocks doing the SQL connection are using ms specified procedures for calling SQL server. Yes data readers.

Comment: The connection string is standard with pooling off for now. As it seemed worse with pooling.

Comment: Please define standard (connection string).

Comment: <add key="ConnectionStringSearch" value="pooling=false;Connection Lifetime=90;Password=;Connect Timeout=999;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Initial Catalog;Data Source=2;Network Library=DBMSSOCN"/>

Comment: @user974308 Please see http://www.connectionstrings.com to correctly construct a connection string.

Comment: Is there a way to run profiler to show created connections that are not disposed of?

Comment: Please post the code in question. **It sounds like you need to stop testing on the production server.**  Have you been able to reproduce this on the testing server, if not, have you confirmed the configuration of both servers are **EXACTLY** the same?

Answer (score 0):

- Read the MS documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx
- Show us what your connection string looks like.
- - Do you have many connection strings?
- - Do you use transactions for all of your SQL requests?
- - - Saying the code properly uses "using" without presenting a snippet of the actual code makes solving your problem difficult
- Correctly enable connection pooling: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx
- - Set Max Pool Size = ?32?, Min Pool Size = ?8?, and MultipleActiveResultSets = true
- Check your SQL Server's maximum allowed connections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx

Comment: Thank you you have given me something to work from. I will do all suggested and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If you include "Application Name=Some String" in your connection string, then in SQL Profiler, there's a column where you can see "Some String" as the name of the application.

If you use a different Application Name everywhere your code opens a connection, that will let you see which connections are still open. It will also effectively disable connection pooling, since pooling compares connections strings to determine which connections should be re-used.

Having said that, it looks like your current connection string is malformed. You might want to fix that first.